# SQL query stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Create a stored procedure that passes in the `SalesOrderID` as a parameter.
This stored procedure will return the `SalesOrderID`, Date of the transaction, shipping date, city and state. It is not running

Ans:

```
Create PROCEDURE proc_findProductInfo
    @SalesOrderID int,
    @SalesOrderOut int OUTPUT,
    @OrderDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @ShipDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @CityState varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SET @SalesOrderOut = @SalesOrderID
    SET @OrderDate = (SELECT OrderDate FROM SALES.SalesOrderHeader )
    SET @ShipDate = (SELECT ShipDate FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader)
    SET @CityState = (SELECT a.City, st.Name
                      FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s  
                      INNER JOIN Person.Address a ON                s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
                      INNER JOIN Person.StateProvince st ON s.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
                      WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID)
END

DECLARE @OrderNum int, @Date datetime, @qty1 int, @Date1 datetime

EXEC proc_findProductInfo 63936, 
                     @SalesOrderOut = @OrderNum OUTPUT,
                     @OrderDate = @Date OUTPUT,
                     @ShipDate = @date1,
                     @CityState = @qty1 output

SELECT @OrderNum, @date, @qty1, @Date1
```

Error Message:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_findProductInfo, Line 25
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Comment: I am getting the following error: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_findProductInfo, Line 25
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: in sub queries need to give where condition like 'WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID' for all the sub queries

Answer (score 1):

You're making this **way** harder than it needs to be:

```
Create PROCEDURE proc_findProductInfo
    @SalesOrderID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT  s.SalesOrderID, s.OrderDate, s.ShipDate, a.City,st.Name
    FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    INNER JOIN Person.Address a ON s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    INNER JOIN Person.StateProvince st ON s.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
    WHERE s.SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
END
```

I'm not even sure you need the StateProvince table here... the question probably allows you to trust the Address record.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining about the following

```
SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          a.City,st.Name
```

You are selecting both City and State Name and trying to assign it to a variable.
You either need to concatenate or coalesce them into them into a single output or alternatively use the below type of select to assign each one to a variable.

```
select 
    @var1 = field1,
    @var2 = field2,
...
```

As below

```
SET @SalesOrderOut = @SalesOrderID

SELECT         @OrderDate = s.OrderDate,
               @ShipDate = s.ShipDate,
               @CityState = CONCAT(a.City, ", ", st.Name)
FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
inner JOIN Person.Address a
ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
inner JOIN Person.StateProvince st
on s.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
WHERE SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
```